# Why LinkButton inside repeater control load whole page? How to handle this issue in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I am using LinkButton in a repeater control inside UpdatePanel in my asp.net project like This

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_test" runat="server">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <div  class="form-group">
                                       <br />
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="itemid"  >
                                                <div id="ab-1" class="moder profile-tile-box">
                    <div class="itemname-box">
                     <asp:Label ID="lbltets" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("itmName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                        </div>
                                  </div>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                                <FooterTemplate>

                                </div>
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
```

This worked fine for me but the problem is when I click on linkbutton it refreshes the whole page and regenerate all controls and close all open Modal.
how do I fix this issue .. please guide

Answer (score 0):

Check runat=server causing postback...try OnClientClick=“...return false” in link button

Comment: i tried this but onclick="linkbtn_click" does not work properly

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your code inside a update panel to prevent a whole page reload

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
      // add your repeater here
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This will do partial postback on the part thats inside the update panel. Incase of modal put it inside the modal so it will not close the modal itself because it will else rebuild the modal resulting in closing it.